# contentEditable отступ( tab)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть пример ниже. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии <kbd>Tab</kbd> вставлялся отступ в тексте (абзац) вместо перехода к следующему элементу страницы?

```
<div class='test' contentEditable='true'>Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно переделывал для себя подобное из ответа на EN.SO

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
[].forEach.call(divs, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let div = this;
      let selection = div.ownerDocument.defaultView.getSelection();
      let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      let tab = document.createTextNode("\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0");
      range.insertNode(tab);
      range.setStartAfter(tab);
      range.setEndAfter(tab);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class='test' id="editor" contentEditable='true'> Some text</div>
```

Comment: А курсор перемещать?

Comment: @Other, перемещается же?

Comment: А почему 4 пробела, а не одна табуляция? )

Comment: После Вашего апдейта - да, перемещается.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko вроде было так, что если див не в `pre` то табуляция интерпретирована будет как пробел. Чтото у меня была с этим проблема.